# Set Event on Button Click XAML Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, visual-c++

I have just obtained a new PC having used a mac my entire life, and am making the shift to visual studio. I am trying to figure out how to use XAML to make a universal app, and was looking at this simple tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn996906.aspx
I have created the basic UI, and when I launch the app I can see all of the text, the text box, and the button. I am now trying to bind an event to the button, so that when I click it it will call a function. The guide says that if I select the button in the XAML and press Alt+Enter then it should bring me to the properties button, where I can choose an 'Events' button and choose 'Click' from a list of events. When I select the line that the button code is on and press Alt+Enter (or F4 as was suggested elsewhere) it brings me to the properties window, but it is empty and there is no 'Actions' button. I have managed to add the function manually, but it seems that if I could generate the function automatically it would save a lot of hassle and make my life much easier. If anybody knows how to do this, I would appreciate their help.

Answer (score 3):

The quickest way is through `XAML` as your typing your front end code in Visual Studio say for a `Button` and you type Click= (see below)

[image]

Visual Studio will prompt you to add a new `Event Handler`. If you hit enter an event will be created for you like so on the backend page.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the name of the function? I realise that this is not often necessary, but is there an easy way without having to swap around between files? If not it isn't the end of the world I guess.

Comment: yes if you highlight the `myButton_Click` right click then `rename` it will change it in all locations

Answer (score 0):

After updating windows and restarting visual studio I was able to access the properties window and change events easily.